# How @PUT some value in webservice via Retrofit

Tags: android, web-services, retrofit

I wanna send a list of integer with userName and password to WebService some thing like bellow request

```
UpdateDocumentState(List<int> documentIds, string userName, string password)
```

But I don't know How to do that ? Use @Post Or @Put ? use @Query Or @Field ? I googled but didn't find any good example or tutorial which explained these well. ( All tutorial I found was about @GET )

could anyone give me some piece of code , how to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About the use of @PUT or @POST I think you had to get this information from the WebService developers.

Anyway, here sample code for both of Retrofit annotations with or without Callback response.

```
@POST("your_endpoint")
void postObject(@Body Object object, Callback<Response> callback);

@PUT("/{path}") 
String foo(@Path("path") String thePath);
```

**EDIT:**
Object is a custom class which represent the data you had to send to the WebService.

```
public class DataToSend {
  public List<Int> myList;
  public String username;
  public String password;
}
```

For example when the @POST annotation declaration will be:

```
@POST
void postList(@Body DataToSend dataToSend, Callback<Response> callback);
```

and then you call the method using Retrofit service

```
yourService.postList(myDataToSend, postCallback);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , In my example Object is something like this myObject(list,userName,password ) ?